# Why can't I sudo some commands? (e.g., vim)

Tags: centos, sudo

I have sudo access on my friends server, running centos-6.3, but when I try to run some commands like `sudo vim /var/www/html/index.html` I get an error `sudo: vim: command not found` I can, however, run `sudo su` and then `vim /var/www/html/index.html` and it works as expected.

`echo $PATH` and `sudo echo $PATH` both yield:

```
/usr/local/bin:/bin:/usr/bin:/usr/local/sbin:/usr/sbin:/sbin:/home/jared/bin
```

`sudo which vim` however yields:

```
which: no vim in (/sbin:/bin:/usr/sbin:/usr/bin)
```

I've tried adding

```
export PATH=$PATH:/usr/local/bin
```

to the `/root/.bashrc` which as fixed the issue when using `sudo su` but not just `sudo <command>`.

How do I get `sudo <command>` to work?

Comment: Have you already added that user to the sudoers in the Centos OS?

Answer (score 19, accepted):

When running `sudo`, many systems are configured to clear the environment of all non-whitelisted values, and to reset the PATH variable to a sanitized value.

You will find the former as `Defaults env_reset` and several `Defaults env_keep += "SOME_VARIABLE_NAME"` in `/etc/sudoers`. The latter "secure" `PATH` override is specified as `Defaults    secure_path = /sbin:/bin:/usr/sbin:/usr/bin` – delete this line to remove this behavior when `sudo`ing.

---

How which environment variable is handled is printed when you run `sudo -V` as `root`.

---

If you don't want to get rid of these defaults, you can always specify programs using their full path (`sudo /usr/local/bin/vim`).

Alternatively, you can allow your account to `SETENV` in the `sudoers` file, for example:

```
%wheel  ALL=(ALL)       SETENV: ALL
```

This allows you to override environment defaults like this: `sudo PATH=$PATH which vim`, as the variable is intepreted by your shell before the command is executed, resulting in an inherited `PATH` (which will likely not include `/sbin` etc. though).

Comment: Thanks. I'll use Dennis' work around until I get the owner to admend the sudoers file.

Answer (score 8):

```
sudo echo $PATH
```

does not do what you think. `$PATH` gets replaced by the (your) shell *before* execuitng the command.

To accomplish the desired behavior, you can use `sudo -i`.

From [man sudo](http://linux.die.net/man/8/sudo):

> -i [command]
>
> The **-i** (*simulate initial login*) option runs the shell specified in the **passwd**(5) entry of the target user as a login shell. This means that login-specific resource files such as `.profile` or `.login` will be read by the shell. If a command is specified, it is passed to the shell for execution.

Comment: This is a suitable workaround until I can get the owner to adjust the sudoers file.

Answer (score 1):

> **How do I get `sudo <command>` to work?**

Until you resolve the problem with paths use a full pathname

```
  sudo /usr/local/bin/vim /var/www/html/index.html
```

Comment: I'm not going to downvote you, but I'm never fond of just working _around_ problems rather than getting right to the point of figuring them out and fixing them.