# sudo: Who am I really?

Tags: linux, sudo

I am experiencing some weird inconsistencies using `sudo`.

**Users:** carl, root
**Command:** `MakeHotdog`

```
root@laptop$ MakeHotdog
Hotdog has been made!

carl@laptop$ MakeHotdog
Hotdog has been made!
```

However, this happens:

```
carl@laptop$ sudo MakeHotdog
bash: MakeHotdog: command not found
```

I thought that whatever was performed through `sudo` would execute the given command with regard to the environment/path variables of the user which you are executing the command *through* (in this case, given no username-parameter, **root**).

This is not an isolated issue. While `sudo` usually works as expected, there are several issues similar to this I keep stumbling across.

Comment: See http://superuser.com/questions/548508/why-cant-i-sudo-some-commands-e-g-vim and http://stackoverflow.com/questions/12996397/command-not-found-when-using-sudo,

Comment: What does `type MakeHotdog` show (as carl) and what does `sudo sh -c "env | grep ^PATH"` (as carl) show? Does `MakeHotdog` exist in the `PATH` the sudo env sees? Maybe `root`'s PATH to `MakeHotdog` is set by root's login scripts (~/.profile etc.). Does `sudo -i MakeHotdog` work?